# How can I give a loop of inputs different values?

Tags: javascript

```
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    let input = document.createElement("input")
    input.type = "radio"
    input[0].value = "High"
    input[1].value = "Medium"
    input[2].value = "Low"
}
```

So I know the last 3 lines of code are invalid but its for visualization. What I am trying to do is make 3 inputs each with a different value, so say when the loop goes through the code once, it will give the first input a value from the second iteration.

Comment: `input.value = ["High", "Medium", "Low"][i]` Note: this is by no means the best way to do this, by the way .... `["High", "Medium", "Low"].forEach(value => ... etc)` far more efficient

Comment: *the first input a value from the second iteration* huh? that's not what your code looks like it's trying to achieve at all

Comment: Yea so the first element will have the value of "High". the second element will have "medium" and the last will have "low" but thank you for the help!

Comment: `input` is not an array but a single element. You you can't do `input[0]`. Furthermore try to access index 0,1,2 in every iteration of the loop, so what sense does your loop make? You should somehow use the index `i`

Comment: note, you'll also need to add the input to the DOM

Comment: *when the loop goes through the code once, it will give the first input a value from the second iteration* Why from the second iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop, you need to create a new `input` for each iteration. However, you want to use predefined values that you can put into an array.

This can be achieved like so:

```js
const levels = ['High', 'Medium', 'Low']; 
const container = document.querySelector('div');
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    const input = document.createElement("input")
    input.type = "radio"
    input.name = 'level';    // this value must be the same across all your radio buttons to make them act as a group
    input.value = levels[i];
    container.appendChild(input);
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```